Unable to make function parameters (callback)
Why can I not do the following:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    run(hello("Hello"))
}

func hello(str string) {
    fmt.Println(str)
}

func run(f func(str string)) {
    f(str)
}

I can do this, but I wanted to have parameters.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    run(hello)
}

func hello() {
    fmt.Println("Hello")
}

func run(f func()) {
    f()
}


I don't understand the first example, hello doesn't return anything and you can't delay evaluation. Is this what you want to do? https://go.dev/play/p/I8ilTeSpxFp

Yes, thanks.. I guess this is what I have to do. I was hoping that there was a way to make run(f func())  "run" the function passed in.

You can create a wrapper for function hello and make that wrapper return a func. Something like this https://go.dev/play/p/NMPNuCG0hwV

Yes, like what Ch3steR has shown, if you want to delay execution you typically would use a closure (often just an inline function literal)

Thanks @Ch3steR good example & "JimB" good suggestion regarding closures.

I ended up doing it like this:
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    hello(func(str string) {
        fmt.Println("hello")
    })
}

func hello(fn func(str string)) {
    fmt.Println("before fn")
    fn("dummy!")
    fmt.Println("after fn")
}

I dont know if it is called a "higher-order functions", "first-class functions" or "callback function".
Thanks for good examples!

What you are tying to do is
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    run(hello, "Hello")
}

func hello(str string) {
    fmt.Println(str)
}

func run(f func(string), str string) {
    f(str)
}

Note that hello is a func(string), while hello("Hello") has no value (it's a function call with no return value).
